# Why will MFC not load a bitmap resource in single modual (.cpp) VS PROJECT?

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

I have code that was first developed with Visual C++ Version 1.52 (working and self taught).  I am now trying to convert it to a Visual Studio project.  It is a single module project written with MFC.  I used the 'project from existing code' option to generate the project which executes just fine but for loading bitmap resources.  I tested the same relevant code (LoadBitmap and LoadImage) in MFC multi-module projects code and they work just fine.  I am able to load bitmap files directly from disk. If I delete the bitmap files from the project there is 22k less size of the code.  The total bitmap file size is 18k. The only error message that I get is '_WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)'.  I am assuming that the default is adequate.  At this point I am thinking that it is a link properties issue because of MFC, but I don't know what that might be.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

```
//header
//
class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{

public:
    CMainWindow();

    //{{AFX_MSG( CMainWindow )
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnDestroy();
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    //}}AFX_MSG

//protected:
    BOOL    flag;
    BOOL    game, turn;
    CWnd    tictic1, tictic2, tictic3, tictic4, tictic5, tictic6, tictic7, tictic8, tictic9;
    CRect   RCT;
    int     id, count;
    CBitmap O, X;

//body
//
    CMainWindow::CMainWindow()
    {
        LoadAccelTable("MainAccelTable");
        Create(NULL, "Tic Tac Toe\0",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, rectDefault, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);

        flag = TRUE;
        id = 0;
        O.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
        X.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP2);
```

If I transplant the relevant code into VS generated MFC documents it works.  The only difference is that all of my code is original Visual C++ Version 1.52 MFC code, in a single .cpp document but all the rest of the code seems to work fine.

Comment: There's a bug in the code we cannot see. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Your first step... After building the project, open the binary (EXE or DLL) in Visual Studio. Yes, the binary, from File-Open. You want to first look at the resource Bitmap and verify it is in the binary and what its identifier is. What is the identifier name in your code? Usually its in a file like `resource.h` and might initially be something like `IDB_BITMAP1`. IDK what it is in your code. When you examine resources look at ID of that bitmap. Typically it will be a raw number in the binary which should match the ID number. If it's something in quotes, then you have id problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, when I has collecting observations for this query, I deleted the two relevant bitmap files from the resources in order the report the difference in file size.  After I added them back in, the functions then work properly.  I think that what I had originally done was when first importing the new resources, I tried selecting the two as a group and when they displayed right, in the resource file, I assumed that it had worked. It apparently didn't. Duh!

Uh, development; after cleaning up my code, I rebuilt it and it wouldn't load bitmap resources. I deleted the resources then installed them again and the program has worked since. So you tell me.  I think that it's serendipitous. Duh!